# Getting the index of similar consecutive elements in list (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to create a function that returns the index of 3 similar consecutive elements in a list. For the list [1,2,3,3,3,4,5] the output sould be myFunc([1,2,3,3,3,4,5]) ---> 2 (or [2]).

The following code does this job:

```
def myFunc(a):
    lst = []
    for i in range(len(a)-2):
        if a[i]==a[i+1]==a[i+2]:
            lst.append(i)
    return lst
```

... but it is time-consuming to check every element in a large list.

The code:

```
def myFunc(a):
    return any(a[i]==a[i+1]==a[i+2] for i in range(len(a)-2))
```

... seems useful for the problem, but I am not sure wether there is a way to get the index of the similar consecutive elements from this (returns True or False)

**My question:**
Is there a way to determine the indexes of similar consecutive elements in a list without using a for loop to check every element? Is there a more elegant way to solve the problem?

Comment: I think you'll find that using `any` still checks every element of the list until it finds an index that satisfies the criteria.

Comment: Your two snippets do totally different things. Do you want the first index? All indices? Both your snippets are O(n), and you can't really do better than that for this task.

Comment: I want all indices, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it in pure Python using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
inList = [1,2,3,3,3,4,5]

def showIndices(inList):
    return list(filter(lambda i: inList[i] == inList[i+1] == inList[i+2], range(len(inList)-2)))

indices = showIndices(inList)
print(indices)
```

Output:

```
[2]
```

Comment: Nice one! I selected this for answer, because it is pure Python (as you said).

Comment: Thank you. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `itertools.groupby()` here to get all indices:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [1,2,3,3,3,4,5]

length = 3

result = []
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), key=itemgetter(1)):
    group = list(g)

    if len(group) == length:
        result.append((k, list(map(itemgetter(0), group))))

print(result)
```

Which gives a list of tuples in the form `[(number, [indices])]`:

```
[(3, [2, 3, 4])]
```

Comment: Such a handy solution. When you need to have duplicate elements with their indices this is the way.

Answer (score 1):

NumPy can do it faster if the list is long:

```
import numpy as np

def myFunc(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    matches = (a[:-2] == a[1:-1]) & (a[1:-1] == a[2:])
    return np.where(matches)[0][0] # take first match index
```

This is roughly 10 to 400 times faster than the itertools solution from RoadRunner (400x if the input is already a NumPy array, closer to 10x if not).